# cancel async task inside of the task

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

hi this is may main function

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        foreach(var user in sommodel)
        {
             AsyncContext.Run(() => sf.StartFollowState(5));
        }
    }
```

and this is task

```
public class StartFollow
{
    public async Task StartFollowState(long iuid)
    {
        foreach(var user in sommodel)
        {
             if(somthing)
             {
                  //cancel a task
             }
              //do some
        }
        foreach(var user in sommodel)
        {
              //do some
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see in the task I want to stop or cancel the task in that foreach
how can I do that ?

Comment: You want to cancel a single task or all the other tasks as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately one does not simply cancel a Task. What you could do is 'return' out of the method so that the Task runs into nirvana and then just wait for the Garbage Collector to do the work.

```
public class StartFollow
{
    public async Task StartFollowState(long iuid)
    {
        foreach(var user in sommodel)
        {
             if(somthing)
             {
                  //cancel a task
                  return;    
             }

             //do some
        }

        foreach(var user in sommodel)
        {
              //do some
        }
    }
}
```